# Scroll to the top of the element click in accordion jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making an accordian, everything works fine, the thing is the content of each element is pretty large and I can't make the element to scroll at the top of title to start reading at the top of the element clicked, I'm trying with `jQuery animate` but is not working.

HTML

```
<dl class="FrecuentlyAsked">
  <dt>
    <h1 data-accordian-title="#accordian-1">Title</h1>
  </dt>
    <dd id="accordian-1">
       Content goes here
    </dd>
  <dt>
    <h1 data-accordian-title="#accordian-2">Title 2</h1>
  </dt>
    <dd id="accordian-2">
       Content goes here
    </dd>     
<dl>
```

Here's my code:

```
// Accordian
function closeAccordion() {
    $('.FrecuentlyAsked dt h1').removeClass('active');
    $('.FrecuentlyAsked dd').slideUp(300);
}

$('.FrecuentlyAsked dt h1').click( function() {
    var currentVal = $(this).attr('data-accordian-title');

    if ($(this.target).is('.active')) {
        closeAccordion();
    } else {
        closeAccordion();
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.FrecuentlyAsked  ' + currentVal).slideDown(300); 
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top}, 800);
    }
});
```

JS Fiddle
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/yLrLy7o2/)

Hope you guys can help me
Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your closeAccordion() method with the code below and it will work fine

```
function closeAccordion() {
   $('.FrecuentlyAsked dt h1').removeClass('active');
   $('.FrecuentlyAsked dd').slideUp(0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I think there was a problem with the delays, but this fixed the issue perfectly!.

Answer (score 0):

use below code
$('.FrecuentlyAsked dd').slideUp(0);

Answer (score 0):

You only edit this row:

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('.FrecuentlyAsked').offset().top}, 800);
```

And here is [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1pvfmrcj/)

Answer (score 0):

I got the Fix, try the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mayanksaxena19/yLrLy7o2/2/),

There is too much delay used that causing the problem.

```
$('.FrecuentlyAsked dt h1').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this); // caching object
        var currentVal = $(this).attr('data-accordian-title');

        if ($(this.target).is('.active')) {
            closeAccordion();
        } else {
            closeAccordion();

                $(this).addClass('active');
                $('.FrecuentlyAsked  ' + currentVal).slideDown(300);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $this.offset().top}, 800);


            }, 400);



        }
    });
```

Hope this helps..